# python: work out intersection of two functions

Tags: python, scipy, nonlinear-optimization, scipy-optimize

I am trying to use `scipy.optimize.fsolve` to work out the x-intercept(s):

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
from numpy import array, empty

counter = 0


def f(x_):
    global counter
    counter += 1
    return pow(x_, 3) * 3 - 9.5 * pow(x_, 2) + 10 * x_


x0_ = empty(2)
x0_[0] = 1
x0_[1] = 6
res = fsolve(f, x0=x0_)
print(counter)
print(res)
```

the function f(x): https://www.desmos.com/calculator/8j8djr01da
the result of this code is:

```
74
[0. 0.]
```

I expect the result to be

```
[0, 1.575, 3.175]
```

Can someone please offer some help.

Plus:
I can't understand the documentation of fsolve(x0), is that just a guess? I will be so appreciated if you can explain.

Plus Plus:
I will be working with lots of linear equations with unknown expressions and exponential, I am really looking for a way to work out the x-intercepts, in other words, the roots by the expression of f(x).I would be so glad if you can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get the set of all roots for a polynomial by

```
numpy.roots([3, -9.5, +10, 0])
```

> ```
> array([1.58333333+0.90905934j, 1.58333333-0.90905934j,
>    0.        +0.j        ])
> ```

It is not clear what your other expected real roots are, `fsolve` will only find the real root `0`.

Of course, if you take the coefficients that you used in the Desmos graphing tool

```
numpy.roots([2, -9.5, +10, 0])
```

you will actually get the expected

> ```
> array([3.17539053, 1.57460947, 0.        ])
> ```

For scalar non-polynomial functions the interface `scipy.optimize.find_root` is perhaps more suitable, especially if you can provide a bracketing interval.

Answer (score 1):

I just want to say that at the first step you define your function wrong:
it should be

```
def f(x_):
  #  global counter
  #  counter += 1
    return pow(x_, 3) * 2 - 9.5 * pow(x_, 2) + 10 * x_
```

but not`pow(x_, 3) * 3 - 9.5 * pow(x_, 2) + 10 * x_`

If you then set `x0_` precisely:

```
x0_=[0,1,3] # according to intersection on graph
res=fsolve(f, x0=x0_)
```

Give you the anticipated output:

```
[0.         1.57460947 3.17539053]
```

Sometimes you just have to be more careful :)